# How-to generate a JKS keystore Report?

Tags: report, keystore, jks

I have been looking for generating a report from a keystore of type JKS. I am looking to see the following details in the report:

Alias Name 
Issued To 
Validity From 
Validity To

I know, this is possible using Keystore manager tool but manually. Is there a way of extracting such information programatically? [or an automated process]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it by the following method:

Create a batch file as followed:

@echo off 
:top 
keytool -list -v -keystore  -storepass  
:enter